# Efficient partial permutation sort in Julia

Tags: sorting, permutation, julia

I am dealing with a problem that requires a partial permutation sort by magnitude in Julia. If `x` is a vector of dimension `p`, then what I need are the first `k` indices corresponding to the `k` components of `x` that would appear first in a partial sort by absolute value of `x`.

Refer to Julia's sorting functions [here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/sort/). Basically, I want a cross between `sortperm` and `select!`. When Julia 0.4 is released, I will be able to obtain the same answer by applying `sortperm!` ([this function](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/sort/#Base.sortperm!)) to the vector of indices and choosing the first `k` of them. However, using `sortperm!` is not ideal here because it will sort the remaining `p-k` indices of `x`, which I do not need.

What would be the most memory-efficient way to do the partial permutation sort? I hacked a solution by looking at the `sortperm` source code. However, since I am not versed in the ordering modules that Julia uses there, I am not sure if my approach is intelligent.

One important detail: I can ignore repeats or ambiguities here. In other words, I do not care about the ordering by `abs()` of indices for two components `2` and `-2`. My actual code uses floating point values, so exact equality never occurs for practical purposes.

```
# initialize a vector for testing
x  = [-3,-2,4,1,0,-1]
x2 = copy(x)
k  = 3    # num components desired in partial sort
p  = 6    # num components in x, x2

# what are the indices that sort x by magnitude?
indices = sortperm(x, by = abs, rev = true)

# now perform partial sort on x2
select!(x2, k, by = abs, rev = true)

# check if first k components are sorted here
# should evaluate to "true"
isequal(x2[1:k], x[indices[1:k]])

# now try my partial permutation sort
# I only need indices2[1:k] at end of day!
indices2 = [1:p]
select!(indices2, 1:k, 1, p, Base.Perm(Base.ord(isless, abs, true, Base.Forward), x))

# same result? should evaluate to "true"
isequal(indices2[1:k], indices[1:k])
```

**EDIT**: With the suggested code, we can briefly compare performance on much larger vectors:

```
p = 10000; k = 100;    # asking for largest 1% of components
x  = randn(p); x2 = copy(x);

# run following code twice for proper timing results
@time {indices = sortperm(x, by = abs, rev = true); indices[1:k]};
@time {indices2 = [1:p]; select!(indices2, 1:k, 1, p, Base.Perm(Base.ord(isless, abs, true, Base.Forward), x))};
@time selectperm(x,k);
```

My output:

```
elapsed time: 0.048876901 seconds (19792096 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.007016534 seconds (2203688 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.004471847 seconds (1657808 bytes allocated)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following version appears to be relatively space-efficient because it uses only an integer array of the same length as the input array:

```
function selectperm (x,k)
    if k > 1 then
        kk = 1:k
    else
        kk = 1
    end
    z = collect(1:length(x))
    return select!(z,1:k,by = (i)->abs(x[i]), rev = true)
end    
x  = [-3,-2,4,1,0,-1]

k  = 3    # num components desired in partial sort
print (selectperm(x,k))
```

The output is:

```
[3,1,2]
```

... as expected.

I'm not sure if it uses less memory than the originally-proposed solution (though I suspect the memory usage is similar) but the code may be clearer and it *does* produce only the first `k` indices whereas the original solution produced all `p` indices.

(Edit)

`selectperm()` has been edited to deal with the `BoundsError` that occurs if `k=1` in the call to `select!()`.

Comment: See my edit of the original question. Your function seems like an overall improvement in speed, memory usage, and readability. Thank you!

Comment: My apologies for reviving this question so many months later, but I only recently encountered the following bug: for the suggested function `selectperm`, setting `k = 1` will throw a `BoundsError()`. Why is that?

Comment: @KevinLKeys: Well spotted. I can't say why the `BoundsError` arises in `select!()` when `k=1` without looking at the source code of `select!()` (though I suspect that it likes `1` but not `[1]` which would be generated from `1:1`) but I've amended `selectperm()` to deal with that case.

Comment: It appears that there is now a [selectperm()](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/sort/) in the standard library so I suggest using that instead of the function shown in this answer.

Comment: thank you for the heads-up and the edit! Unfortunately for me, the `selectperm()` function is particular to Julia v0.4, so I cannot use it (yet) since my code base is stuck in v0.3. For the v0.3 code I will make sure to incorporate your suggested changes. When I port to v0.4 I will exploit the new `selectperm()` function.